# Inherit or set choises on ForeignKey Django model

Tags: django, foreign-keys, default, models

Let's take these models:

```
from .choices import STATUS_CHOISES   

class Status(models.Model):
    current_status = models.CharField("Current status", max_length=50, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='new')
    status_change_date = models.DateField(verbose_name="Status change date", default=datetime.datetime.now())

class ProductRequest(models.Model):
    destination = models.CharField("Product Destination", max_length=255)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status)
```

Choices:

```
STATUS_CHOICES = (
('new', 'New'),
('ongoing', 'Ongoing'),
('finalized', 'Finalized'),
)
```

I need to set the same default and use the same choices from the original model on ForeignKey. How can i do that?

Comment: Take a look at this article: http://www.mechanicalgirl.com/post/dynamic-choices-on-a-foreignkey-field/. Hope it'll give you some ideas.

Comment: I think it's impossible because the foreignkey is based on PK not the choices

Answer (score 0):

Decided going to simple attribute:

```
class ProductRequest(models.Model):
    destination = models.CharField("Product Destination", max_length=255)
    status = models.CharField("Request Status", max_length=50, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='new')
```

looking for a way to store status change date..